# Invalid Region and Span in display annotation on mapview in ios 7

Tags: ios, iphone, sdk

Hi I would like to display multiple annotation of current user.I would like to update it in some time interval but I am trying but got in valid resign and span issue.any help is appreciated.

```
id<AppDelegate> theDelegate = (id<AppDelegate>) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
AppMediator *mediator  = (AppMediator*) theDelegate.mediator;
watchEntityLocationList=[mediator watchNowList];
[watchEntityLocationList retain];
[mapView setDelegate:self];
for(WatchEntityLocation *watchEntityLocation in watchEntityLocationList)
{locationArray=watchEntityLocation.locationList;
    NSLog(@"location count:%i",[locationArray count]);
    Location *location=[locationArray objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"watcher latlong:%g,%g",location.latitude,location.longitude);
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate= CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.latitude,location.longitude);
    if (CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(coordinate)) {
          NSLog(@"valid Cordinate!");
    } else {
         NSLog(@"Invalid Cordinate!");}
    NSLog(@"latitude is::%g" , coordinate.latitude);
    NSLog(@"latitude is: :%g" , coordinate.longitude);
    MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinate, 0.5*METERS_PER_MILE, 0.5*METERS_PER_MILE);
    MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [mapView regionThatFits:viewRegion];
    if ((adjustedRegion.center.latitude >= -90) && (adjustedRegion.center.latitude <= 90) && (adjustedRegion.center.longitude >= -180) && (adjustedRegion.center.longitude <= 180)){NSLog(@"valid region!");
        [mapView setRegion:[mapView regionThatFits:adjustedRegion] animated:TRUE];
    }else{
         NSLog(@"Invalid region!");
    }[self addAnnotation:coordinate tlocation:watchEntityLocation.watchEntity.name];
}
```

Comment: You put && operator check it

Comment: I have tried another way just (adjustedRegion.center.longitude >= -180) but its still invalid region.I got already this issue before put  condition so its some know reason so I got wrong location

Comment: What's the _exact_ error message you're getting?  Note that region has a center and a span so technically you need to check the span as well.  Unrelated but you don't need to call setRegion before adding each annotation.

Comment: I am getting invalid region and when its display user location address it display wrong place in mapview

Comment: By _exact_ error message, I meant show the full and actual text including the center and span that the map view doesn't like.

Comment: 1
down vote
favorite
I'm trying to get a annotation that show the callout automatically. I have managed to do so, but when this is done the map zooms in on the middle of the Arctic Ocean for some reason. Anyone have an idea why that happens?

Comment: You should ask that as a separate question and include the code.  But the obvious would be to check what coordinates you are telling the map view to zoom to.

Comment: hey I just asked separate question with all source code.any help appreciated thanks

Comment: you can look it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20122849/getting-wrong-annotation-location-on-mapview

Answer (score 0):

Its may be latitude and longitude data type or assign value issue