# Getting Wrong Annotation location on Mapview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7

I'm getting the wrong annotation location on `Mapview`. I have tried so many things, but with no luck.
I'm getting the right coordinate but it's displayed at the wrong location on mapview. Does anyone know why?

```
  for(WatchEntityLocation *watchEntityLocation in watchEntityLocationList)
    {
        locationArray=watchEntityLocation.locationList;
        NSLog(@"location count:%i",[locationArray count]);
        Location *location=[locationArray objectAtIndex:0];

        NSLog(@"watcher latlong:%g,%g",location.latitude,location.longitude);
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate= CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.latitude,location.longitude);

        if (CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(coordinate)) {
              NSLog(@"valid Cordinate!");
        } else {
             NSLog(@"Invalid Cordinate!");
        }

        NSLog(@"latitude is::%g" , coordinate.latitude);
        NSLog(@"longitude is: :%g" , coordinate.longitude);

        MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinate, 0.5*METERS_PER_MILE, 0.5*METERS_PER_MILE);
        MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [mapView regionThatFits:viewRegion];

        NSLog(@"adjustedRegion latitude is::%g" , adjustedRegion.center.latitude);
        NSLog(@"adjustedRegion longitude is: :%g" ,adjustedRegion.center.longitude);

        if ((adjustedRegion.center.latitude >= -90) && (adjustedRegion.center.latitude <= 90) && (adjustedRegion.center.longitude >= -180) && (adjustedRegion.center.longitude <= 180)){
            NSLog(@"valid region!");
             [mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];
              mapView.showsUserLocation = NO;
        }else{
             NSLog(@"Invalid region!");
        }
        [self addAnnotation:adjustedRegion.center tlocation:watchEntityLocation.watchEntity.name];}

-(void)addAnnotation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)lcordinate tlocation:(NSString *)name
{
    MyAnnotation *annotation =
    [[MyAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinates:lcordinate
                                        title:name
                                     subTitle:@""];

    annotation.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
    [mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
    [annotationArray addObject:annotation];
}

    - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
    {
    for (MKAnnotationView *av in views) {
        id <MKAnnotation> mp = [av annotation];
        if (![mp isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        {
            [mv selectAnnotation:mp animated:YES];
            break;
        }
    }
    }

    - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id     <MKAnnotation>)annotation
      {
      if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;
    if(annotation != map.userLocation)
    {
        MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"MyPin"];
        annView.animatesDrop=TRUE;
        annView.canShowCallout = YES;
        [annView setSelected:YES];
        annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
        annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(15, 15);
        return annView;
    }
```

Comment: How many annotations are being added?  If not too many, please show the NSLog output (add it to the question).  Also, when calling your addAnnotation:tlocation: method (ie. `[self addAnnotation:...`), you are passing `adjustedRegion.center`.  It would be more accurate to pass the un-adjusted `coordinate` which you obtained from locationList.  As mentioned in a previous question, you do not need to call setRegion before adding _each and every_ annotation.

Comment: hi I am adding multiple annotation and which is 
["suchi","suchi@gmail.com","23.0494","72.5663","301"],["Jeet","jeet@gmail.com","23.0494","72.5661","301"],["Hitesh Vaghela","hiteshvaghela116@yahoo.com","37.7858","-122.406","301"]]}
and I have changed according to your above suggestion but still same issue

Comment: when when I I am putting it static then its give correct location but when I put dynamically then its give wrong location.I used same data type.

Comment: The first two annotations are in India and the third one is in San Francisco.  Where are they appearing in the map?  The reason I asked for the actual NSLog output is to see what the code is actually reading and doing (not what you think it should be doing) but you've shown the original raw data instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think check your lat-long datatype and its value.